# QGIS empty date field shows value in custom form

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to define custom form. Problem is with date field- form shows value even if it's empty. Is there a way to set it to show only the existing values?

Comment: There is an option to **Allow NULL values**. If you check this, empty fields are shown as _NULL_; otherwise values are shown.

Comment: Unfortunately- not working in 2.8 for me. Not in Autogenerete/Drag'n'drop nor with UI. Could there be some other reasons

Comment: Strange, I tested this on QGIS 2.8.2 and it works. When you checked the NULL options box, did you edit and then **save** the attributes? I don't think the changes appear immediately when you check the option.

Comment: Correction- problem is not with Autogenerete/Drag'n'drop  but with UI. Maybe there's some setting that does the same as "Allow Null values" in QT Designer

Comment: Big issue: it is not possible to validate this **NULL** date value in **Python init function**.